# Facebook Interstitial Ad Crash Mopub Plugin on Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, mopub

i realised Facebook Interstitial Ad crashes with Mopub Plugin when I check the crashes on organizer

I can see backtraces on organizer.

I want to find true file to edit and fix this crash.

This is the backtrace:
[image: Backtrace]

And this is the way i used

File:AdSystem.cs

```
try {
    MoPub.showInterstitialAd(adUnit.key1);
}
catch(Exception e) {
}
```

And this is the Facebook Interstitial Adaptor for Mopub
https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/tree/master/AdNetworkSupport/Facebook

File:FacebookInterstitialCustomEvent.m

```
//
//  FacebookInterstitialCustomEvent.m
//  MoPub
//
//  Copyright (c) 2014 MoPub. All rights reserved.
//

#import <FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.h>
#import "FacebookInterstitialCustomEvent.h"

#import "MPInstanceProvider.h"
#import "MPLogging.h"

@interface MPInstanceProvider (FacebookInterstitials)

- (FBInterstitialAd *)buildFBInterstitialAdWithPlacementID:(NSString *)placementID
                                                  delegate:(id<FBInterstitialAdDelegate>)delegate;

@end

@implementation MPInstanceProvider (FacebookInterstitials)

- (FBInterstitialAd *)buildFBInterstitialAdWithPlacementID:(NSString *)placementID
                                                  delegate:(id<FBInterstitialAdDelegate>)delegate
{
    FBInterstitialAd *interstitialAd = [[FBInterstitialAd alloc] initWithPlacementID:placementID];
    interstitialAd.delegate = delegate;
    return interstitialAd;
}

@end

@interface FacebookInterstitialCustomEvent () <FBInterstitialAdDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) FBInterstitialAd *fbInterstitialAd;

@end

@implementation FacebookInterstitialCustomEvent

- (void)requestInterstitialWithCustomEventInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    if (![info objectForKey:@"placement_id"]) {
        MPLogError(@"Placement ID is required for Facebook interstitial ad");
        [self.delegate interstitialCustomEvent:self didFailToLoadAdWithError:nil];
        return;
    }

    MPLogInfo(@"Requesting Facebook interstitial ad");

    self.fbInterstitialAd =
    [[MPInstanceProvider sharedProvider] buildFBInterstitialAdWithPlacementID:[info objectForKey:@"placement_id"]
                                                                     delegate:self];

    [self.fbInterstitialAd loadAd];
}

- (void)showInterstitialFromRootViewController:(UIViewController *)controller {
    if (!self.fbInterstitialAd || !self.fbInterstitialAd.isAdValid) {
        MPLogError(@"Facebook interstitial ad was not loaded");
        [self.delegate interstitialCustomEventDidExpire:self];
    } else {
        MPLogInfo(@"Facebook interstitial ad will be presented");
        [self.delegate interstitialCustomEventWillAppear:self];
        [self.fbInterstitialAd showAdFromRootViewController:controller];
        MPLogInfo(@"Facebook interstitial ad was presented");
        [self.delegate interstitialCustomEventDidAppear:self];
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    _fbInterstitialAd.delegate = nil;
}

#pragma mark FBInterstitialAdDelegate methods

- (void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(FBInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
{
    MPLogInfo(@"Facebook intersitital ad was loaded. Can present now");
    [self.delegate interstitialCustomEvent:self didLoadAd:interstitialAd];
}

- (void)interstitialAd:(FBInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    MPLogInfo(@"Facebook intersitital ad failed to load with error: %@", error.description);
    [self.delegate interstitialCustomEvent:self didFailToLoadAdWithError:nil];
}

- (void)interstitialAdDidClick:(FBInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
{
    MPLogInfo(@"Facebook interstitial ad was clicked");
    [self.delegate interstitialCustomEventDidReceiveTapEvent:self];
}

- (void)interstitialAdDidClose:(FBInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
{
    MPLogInfo(@"Facebook interstitial ad was closed");
    [self.delegate interstitialCustomEventDidDisappear:self];
}

- (void)interstitialAdWillClose:(FBInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
{
    MPLogInfo(@"Facebook interstitial ad will close");
    [self.delegate interstitialCustomEventWillDisappear:self];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Official site of Mopub,

You should Pre-fetch an interstitial:

```
MoPub.requestInterstitialAd(interstitialAdUnit);
```

In this case,

```
MoPub.requestInterstitialAd(adUnit.key1);
```

Then Show the interstitial:

```
MoPub.showInterstitialAd (interstitialAdUnit);
```

In your case,

```
MoPub.showInterstitialAd (adUnit.key1);
```

So, your file AdSystem.cs should be

```
try {
    MoPub.requestInterstitialAd(adUnit.key1);
    MoPub.showInterstitialAd(adUnit.key1);
}
catch(Exception e) {
}
```

**These callback handlers will help you too**

```
void onInterstitialLoaded (string adUnitId)
void onInterstitialFailed (string errorMsg)
void onInterstitialDismissed (string adUnitId)
void interstitialDidExpire (string adUnitId)
void onInterstitialShown (string adUnitId)
void onInterstitialClicked (string adUnitId)
```

For more details, have a look at [Mopub's Official Documentation](http://www.mopub.com/resources/docs/unity+engine+integration/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have already pre-fetch interstitial. My code is working perfectly but some of devices crashes. I just want to fix the crash

Comment: Can you provide 2 or 3 example devices names.

Comment: Iphone 6s 10.2
Iphone SE 10.2
Iphone 5s 10.2.1
Iphone 6 10.2

I think some of facebook ads crashes. If we fix FacebookInterstitialCustomEvent.m file by using try catch we can get rid of this crash?